# How to export client-facing, dynamically updated array to an Express router to be queried into a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, google-maps

I am creating an app that uses the Google Maps API to search for locations and dynamically update a `markersData` array each time a new location is searched. Here is the code in app.js that creates an updates that array.

```
 let markersData = [];

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener("places_changed", () => {
    // get the places from the search box
    const places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    // if there are not places, exit the function
    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // loop through each place
    places.forEach((place) => {
      // check if the place has geometry and location data
      if (!place.geometry || !place.geometry.location) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }

      // get the latitude, longitude, and name of the place
      const lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
      const lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
      const name = place.name;

      // add latitude, longitude, and name to the markersData array
      markersData.push({
        lat,
        lng,
        name,
      });

      // log current status of markersData
      console.log("markersData", markersData);
```

Now, I want to use the data from that array to update my PostgreSQL database using a query. This is the code that I currently have for that in my markers-routes.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router  = express.Router();
// write a require here for getting the data from the database
const db = require('../db/connection');
// import markersData array
const markersData = require('public/scripts/app.js');

// ** This code works assuming that I have already obtained the mapId value from the maps table somehow
// loop through each item in the markersData array
markersData.forEach(async (marker) => {
  try {
    // construct SQL query with placeholders for the parameterized values
    const query = `
    INSERT INTO points (latitude, longitude, name, map_id)
    VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
    `;

    // execute the query with the parameterized values
    const result = await db.query(query, [marker.lat, marker.lng, marker.name, mapId]);

    console.log(`Inserted ${result.rowCount} row(s)`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})


module.exports = router;
```

I've tried using `module.exports` to export the array into markers-routes.js but I soon realized that that's not possible since app.js is client-facing and is run by the browser. I've looked up different ways of doing it like using an HTTP Post requests and other npm packages that allow you to package up what's in the file into a exportable module, but I don't know what would be best in my case. Any help would be appreciated.